# eclipse linked resource not found by jsp

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have an eclipse (juno) workspace with some maven projects, the source directories always appeared under a folder called "java resources".

because of some migration at the office, I had to create a new workspace and reimport the projects. now the "java resources" folder is gone and the source directories appear directly under the project root.

This is messing with some linked resources in jsp files I have. there is a jsp file in a project which is imported in many other files, in other projects. There is a link in those extra projects to where the file is so that it can be found. previously the link was found ok, but now instead of looking the file starting in the root of the source directory, it is looking it in the root of the project:

<%@include file="/common/includes/global.jsp"%>
and I'm getting Fragment "/common/includes/global.jsp" was not found at expected path /MYPROJECT/common/includes/global.jsp

update- I thought that the problem with the linked resource was caused by this configuration. I already solved the java resources issues and the jsp still doesnt find the file

Answer (score 0):

I looked for the configuration files in the old workspace and I found that the org.eclipse.wst.common.component file under .settings was different.  the tag defaultRootSoruce as incorrect, since the jsps in my project are not under the standard maven layout.

This fixed it: